# Are there good Grails sample applications from which to learn?

Tags: grails

Besides the sample applications featured in the books *Beginning Groovy and Grails* and *The Definitive Guide to Grails*, are there any applications out there written in Grails that are good examples from which to learn best practices? Such as real applications that are open-source?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

During my learning phase, I came across several good sample applications.

This sample web album app got me started on grails.  It covers security, image upload / manipulation, basic crud etc.

http://www.syger.it/Tutorials/GrailsWebAlbum.html

Here's one from Glen Smith, author of the upcoming Grails in Action book.  The source code to the groovy blog aggregator is located here:

http://code.google.com/p/groovyblogs/

Here's another one by Glen, a blog engine written with grails:

http://code.google.com/p/gravl/

And finally, here's the code to the grails.org site which includes wiki functionality:

http://github.com/grails/grails/tree/master/grails-samples/grails.org/

Comment: The grails.org source is now at https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website

Comment: jup and also more sample apps are listed on https://github.com/grails-samples

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  IBM has an excellent series of articles building on to a sample application at  IBM's developerworks site:

Part I:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/

The Series:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=mastering+grails

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in seeing an application which is pre-built which also incorporates the Grails specific testing practices and approaches (as well as some widely practised testing methods as used within Grails), the Winelovers application outlines a fully working app and a number of different testing angles which can be applied to create confidence and increase testing coverage for your apps.

https://svn.energizedwork.com/skunkworks/grails/WineLovers/

There is also a [presentation](http://docs.google.com/Presentation?id=dgb5cmdc_8jgvfzdd3) which accompanies this which goes into samples and pros and cons.

I will be following up this work with a greater number of examples and further tutorial type updates to help draw out the benefits of testing this way and this much.

Comment: The first link has an extra http:// in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding Stephane's new application to the list:

> Stephane Maldini ✆  to user    show
>   details Oct 21     Hi folks,
>
> I'm pleased to announce the release of
>   a relatively big grails App called
>   iceScrum
>   (http://www.icescrum.org/demo). Code
>   is under a mix of Apache Licence2 ,
>   LGPL and AGPL for the core
>   views/design (
>   http://github.com/icescrum/iceScrum ).
>
> What you can expect to see in this
>   sample (and if you want to reuse the
>   view taglibs behind (140 and more
>   tags)
>
> - Jquery widgets : Tables, Postits, Windows, Widgets, Orderable Menu Bar,
>     Drag And Drop, Key shortcuts .........
> - Real time push for jquery with ICEpush
> - Activity plugin ( "someone has done something")
> - AJAX paradigm for view (url is http://app/project/#view/action/id )
>     like GMAIL, history fully supported.
> - Application of SpringSecurity ACL, Springcache, Resources plugin and many
>     others
> - Window/Widget paradigm on controller just by adding static ui = true (use
>     icescrum Web Component plugins inside)
>     It will be released separatly when
>     time will come
> - Jasper integration
> - Jquery Chart integration
> - many many things which deserve a lot of documentation, at this time you
>     will have to explore yourself some
>     parts.
>
> The app purpose is to offer to agile
>   teams a tool to share a dashboard (for
>   collaborative consultants etc),
>   reports, stories, track bugs and so.
>   It will have his own evolution + some
>   profressional services for better
>   integration in IT via plugins or
>   simply hosting.

Answer (score 2):

... have you looked at weceem?
http://www.weceem.org/weceem/

Answer (score 1):

A very good series that builds a sample app: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=mastering+grails

Answer (score 0):

I second the IBM series Ray Tayek mentioned, and the energizedwork.com example j pimmel mentioned.  The latter has been my reference manual for writing well-tested code and I can't live without it.

Answer (score 0):

The new (Grails 2.0) GEvents app from Paolo Foletto needs to be in this list. There are step-by-step apps leading to the complete app. https://github.com/pfoletto/GEvents/wiki/GrailsWorkshop

There's a working version at http://www.grailsworkshop.com/GEvents/.