# Why this source code doesn't work in Grails 1.3.7?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm a novice in Grails and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276928/are-there-good-grails-sample-applications-from-which-to-learn) question. And I thought of testing [this](http://code.google.com/p/gravl/downloads/list) link as one of the answer suggest.

I downloaded it and when I ran the grails app, I get an error message stating that the version is low and I need to upgrade it. And I did the same using `grails upgrade` command.

After doing this also, when I run the code I get a big error like this :

```
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1123)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1104)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1060)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1003)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:295)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:277)
```

And this error message continues. I don't know whether the source code has an error in it. Since a novice in Grails I couldn't figure out what this error message states.

Can anyone explain me this. And where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to post the start of the exception...

Comment: @tim_yates : It is very big error and I couldn't scroll up to find the top most part of exception :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the top part of the stacktrace, so it's hard to know what's going on since what you're showing is fairly generic.

Regardless, since the code hasn't been updated in over three years and is running a very old version of Grails (1.0.1), simply running `grails upgrade` won't do much, even if it doesn't fail like you saw. There are too many important changes between 1.0.1 and 1.3.7.

If you do want to play with that code you should contact the author. But keep in mind that he doesn't even use gravl himself anymore - he recently switched to WordPress.