# Are there any good grails 2 example/demos out there?

Tags: grails, demo

Being new to grails, but not to application development frameworks, the first thing I want to do is see what can be done and what is possible - show case projects or production websites or sophisticated examples.

I found this post: [Are there good Grails sample applications from which to learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276928/are-there-good-grails-sample-applications-from-which-to-learn)  But the links are either dead, or the projects 5 years out of date.

So far I have only found trivial examples which don't have the kind of features required by a medium sized app (such as tree or menu based navigation), and all look the same, and with navigation of a 1990s website, rather than a web 2  web app.

The testimonial page on grails.org is mainly links to corporate websites who claim to have used it as part of their system, rather than runnable demos.

Any one got any links to running demos (ideally with source) built with grails?

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend you look around on GitHub for public projects which are based on Grails. The first one that comes to mind is [Asgard by NetFlix](https://github.com/Netflix/asgard). A bit of digging there can really turn up some great examples. The [Grails website](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website) itself is also on GitHub and has some good examples of how various plugins can be used.

[Spud CMS](https://github.com/spud-grails/spud-cms) which is built on Grails is a good example you can find on GitHub as well.